# perl oneliner search replace pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have thousands of rows where some contain the following:

```
id_s,title_dk
KKS2826,"Søslag ved Øland og Gulland, 1564",12312,2x2
KKS935,"Vignet til Edvard Brandes, afhandling om Johan Wiehe", 1233, 4x4
```

I'm looking for a Perl one-liner where I can delete any comma that might occur within quotations (the second column). But obviously not the others, wince they are delimiters.

So desired output would be:

```
id_s,title_dk
KKS2826,"Søslag ved Øland og Gulland 1564",12312,2x2
KKS935,"Vignet til Edvard Brandes afhandling om Johan Wiehe", 1233, 4x4
```

I have been playing with this:  `perl -ne 's/(?<!,),//g; print;'`
But I can't figure out how to keep the other commas.

Comment: sorry. Format was wrong

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to modify your data so that it can be parsed by just splitting on commas. Commas, spaces, and even double-quotes within quoted fields are fine in "standard" CSV data, and you should fix your parser instead of mutilating your data.

Answer (score 3):

Easy using [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV_XS):

```
perl -CS -MText::CSV_XS=csv -we '
    my $aoa = csv(in => shift, allow_whitespace => 1);
    $_->[1] =~ s/,//g for @$aoa;
    csv(in => $aoa, out => *STDOUT, always_quote => 0);
    ' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner

```
perl -p -e  's/"([^"]*)"/my $m=$1;$m=~ s:,::g; $m /eg' file.txt
```

As per Borodin comment script updated. Because above script will remove the `"` also.

```
perl -p -e  's/ (?<=") ([^"]*) (?<=")/$1=~ s:,::rg; /xeg' file.txt
```

In second one, I used positive look ahead and look behind. With non-destructive  modifier `(r)`. Non-destructive modifier will work on only > 5.14.

Comment: `perl -pe  's{ " ( [^"]+ ) " }{ $1 =~ tr/,//dr }xeg' file.txt`

Comment: Your solution removes the double quotes, which wasn't part of the requirement

Comment: @Borodin Yours snippet also not removing the `"`. And thank you for you comment. I learn one method from you. Answer updated.

Comment: I have met this problem on various datasets - not just csv. That's why I'm looking for a generic way of dealing with this kind of regex problem: how do you do only-in-group-search/replace